# Как правильно настроить laravel mix?

Tags: laravel-mix

Есть проект на laravel. В нем используется vuejs компоненты. Фронт собирается mix'ом. Проблема в том, что при включенной опции `extractVueStyles:true` перестает работать `mix.less()` и `mix.sass`
Результирующий файл собирается без основных стилей, только стили из компонентов vuejs.

Мой конфиг:

```
mix.options({
    extractVueStyles: true,
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/js/devices.js','public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/sass')
   .less('resources/less/app.less', 'public/css/less')
    .styles([
        'public/css/sass/app.css',
        'public/css/less/app.css',
    ],'public/css/app.css')
;
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы и стили из компонентов, и основные стили вставлялись в один файл css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по официальной документации mix, ключ `extractVueStyles` может принимать значения `true/false`. Но как оказалось, что еще можно указать строку:

```
mix.options({
    extractVueStyles: 'css/components.css',
});
```

Тогда  в `public/css` (в моем случае) создастся файл со стилями компонентов.